# Как создавать триггер для новых таблиц?

Tags: postgresql

Подскажите пожалуйста. Может кто знает или встречался с решением данной проблемы. Есть оборудование, в процессы которого я залезть не могу. Это оборудования работает с posgreSQL. Каждый час оно генерирует новую таблицу (бред бредом). Каждая таблица имеет своё уникальное название. Я написал триггер. Если добавлять триггер вручную к каждой новой таблице, всё работает отлично. Однако я не хочу вручную добавлять триггеры к новым таблицам(24 таблицы в день). Если ли возможность на уровне самой бд автоматически добавлять триггер к каждой новой бд? Возможно ли написать функцию, которая будет на sql запрос CREATE TABLE создавать таблицу и к ней добавлять триггер?
Может ещё какие-то решения существуют?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: [DDL-триггер](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createeventtrigger.html)?

Comment: [This can be done with an event trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44388311/4496422)

Comment: @Yaant, спасибо, я два дня не мог найти ничего подобного!

Comment: @nörbörnën, спасибо, пример прям то, что надо!